# WM_DROPFILES not received after drag&drop file over icon

Tags: winapi, drag-and-drop

I have a WINAPI application and I want to start it by drag and drop of a file onto the Icon of my application.

The main window is created with

```
hWnd = CreateWindow("app-name",
                    "",
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
                    | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
                    | WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

and has a WndProc with

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK
WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                DragAcceptFiles(hWnd, TRUE);

                // etc (other controls and windows created here)

            }
            break;
        case WM_DROPFILES:
           {
             char filename[MAX_PATH];
             HDROP hDropInfo = (HDROP) wParam;
             DragQueryFile(hDropInfo, 0, filename, MAX_PATH);
             // etc open file... 
           }
           break;
```

The problem is that when I drag and drop a file from the Explorer onto my program Icon, the program is started, but I don't receive any WM_DROPFILES message. That is also the case if I configure the file-type to "open with" my program - it's started but no WM_DROPFILES is received.

But once the program is initialized I can drag a drop a file into some of its windows, and then I get the WM_DROPFILES message as I expect it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for advice!

BR Alfred

Comment: The `WM_DROPFILES` message is for dropping file on your running application, not the icon of a non-running application. (After all, a non-running application does not have a window.) For the latter case, you get the file name on the command line.

Comment: Thank you, so I can use the function  GetCommandLine();

Comment: or better I use argument 2 of fucntion WinMain : lpCmdLine

Comment: If you are using the CRT that ships with Visual Studio, you get access to the parsed command line using [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727674.aspx).

Comment: Calling `DragAcceptFiles` is unnecessary if you have `WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES` set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use the `lpCmdLine` argument of `WinMain` function:

```
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    // remove double quotes from filename with spaces
    if( lpCmdLine[0] == '"' ) {
        lpCmdLine++;
        lpCmdLine[strlen(lpCmdLine)-1] = 0;
    }

    printf("%s\n",lpCmdLine);

    // ...
}
```